# Error in console when running on Flutter web: Refused to execute script from localhost/main.js, because MIME type ('text/html') is not executable

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

We are trying to run our Flutter app in web. The app runs, but not everything is working as aspected. We get this error on Chrome:

*Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8888/main.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.*

In Safari, this is the error:

*Refused to execute http://localhost:8888/main.js as script because "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" was given and its Content-Type is not a script MIME type.*

This is our *index.html* in the web folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <base href="/">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta name="description" content="Test page">

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

    <title>Title page</title>
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@2.12.313/build/pdf.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@2.12.313/build/pdf.worker.min.js";
    pdfRenderOptions = {
      cMapUrl: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@2.12.313/cmaps/',
      cMapPacked: true,
    }
  </script>

<script src="main.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="jsapi.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

This is the flutter doctor output:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.5, on macOS 12.2.1 21D62 darwin-x64, locale nl-NL)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.72.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

Does anyone have an idea what causes the error? Thanks! :)

Comment: The right answer can be found in this response https://stackoverflow.com/a/75335747/13085174