# Flutter Web App not starting: The script has an unsupported MIME type

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, vercel

My flutter web app won't start, I see the following errors in the browser console:

[image]

This behavior only occurs when deployed on vercel. I don't get this error when deploying on firebase hosting.

Furthermore, this error only occurs for nested routes. It works when I open my deployed app without a subpath in the URL.

The error must occur somewhere in the `loadEntrypoint` function

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function (ev) {
    console.log("LOAD!");
    // Download main.dart.js
    _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
      serviceWorker: {
        serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
      }
    }).then(function (engineInitializer) {
    console.log("INIT");
      return engineInitializer.initializeEngine();
    }).then(function (appRunner) {
    console.log("RUN");
      return appRunner.runApp();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Interesting here is that it says `Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://domainname.net/home/')` even though I load the page `https://domainname.net/home/questionnaire`. In general I expect it would register the ServiceWorker at `https://domainname.net` but I don't know much about ServiceWorkers anyways...

I'm especially puzzled about this because this only happens on vercel but as the error occurs somewhere in `web/index.js`, it assume my hosting provider should have not influence on this behavior?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem.

When I replace the script in my question above with the following script, it seems to resolve the issue.

```
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
    var scriptLoaded = false;
    function loadMainDartJs() {
      if (scriptLoaded) {
        return;
      }
      scriptLoaded = true;
      var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
      scriptTag.src = 'main.dart.js';
      scriptTag.type = 'application/javascript';
      document.body.append(scriptTag);
    }

    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      // Service workers are supported. Use them.
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        // Wait for registration to finish before dropping the <script> tag.
        // Otherwise, the browser will load the script multiple times,
        // potentially different versions.
        var serviceWorkerUrl = 'flutter_service_worker.js?v=' + serviceWorkerVersion;
        navigator.serviceWorker.register(serviceWorkerUrl)
          .then((reg) => {
            function waitForActivation(serviceWorker) {
              serviceWorker.addEventListener('statechange', () => {
                if (serviceWorker.state == 'activated') {
                  console.log('Installed new service worker.');
                  loadMainDartJs();
                }
              });
            }
            if (!reg.active && (reg.installing || reg.waiting)) {
              // No active web worker and we have installed or are installing
              // one for the first time. Simply wait for it to activate.
              waitForActivation(reg.installing ?? reg.waiting);
            } else if (!reg.active.scriptURL.endsWith(serviceWorkerVersion)) {
              // When the app updates the serviceWorkerVersion changes, so we
              // need to ask the service worker to update.
              console.log('New service worker available.');
              reg.update();
              waitForActivation(reg.installing);
            } else {
              // Existing service worker is still good.
              console.log('Loading app from service worker.');
              loadMainDartJs();
            }
          });

        // If service worker doesn't succeed in a reasonable amount of time,
        // fallback to plaint <script> tag.
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (!scriptLoaded) {
            console.warn(
              'Failed to load app from service worker. Falling back to plain <script> tag.',
            );
            loadMainDartJs();
          }
        }, 4000);
      });
    } else {
      // Service workers not supported. Just drop the <script> tag.
      loadMainDartJs();
    }
  </script>
```

Unfortunately, I have not really found out what exactly the problem was and why this is fixing it but I noticed this issue was occurring only since I updated my flutter version and regenerate my index.html. The script I'm now using is the script used by an older flutter version. I'm not sure if this has other effects but for now I'm going with the older script.

Answer (score 6):

- It is caused by this bug: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/116360
- It is already fixed in master: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/118684
- Unfortunately, the fix is not in the stable channel yet (as of 3/02/22), but there is a [cherry-pick request](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/120197).

**Temporal workaround:** ([ref](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/116360#issuecomment-1364181861))

Add these two lines in your `index.html`:

```html
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        entrypointUrl: "/main.dart.js", // <-- THIS LINE
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
          serviceWorkerUrl: "/flutter_service_worker.js?v=", // <-- THIS LINE
        },
        onEntrypointLoaded: function(engineInitializer) {
          engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function(appRunner) {
            appRunner.runApp();
          });
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Run into the same issue today.

After trying many times, I realized the file **flutter.js** was not included in the build folder after running the command.

```
flutter build web
```

It was generating the **build/web** folder but missing some files. No idea why.

The fact is that after running the command `flutter run web --release` the folder **build/web** was populated correctly and I could see the "flutter.js" file in the folder.

After the deployment (in my case firebase hosting) everything was back to normal and working.

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't seem to fix it for me

Comment: Is the file flutter.js in your build/web folder?